# Is node.js suitable for long polling which requires an open connection at all times?

Tags: node.js

I have an online now feature which requires me to set a field in my database which I have integrated into getting notification updates. As such this is being done via long polling (since short polling it isn't much better and this results in less connections to the server).

I used to do this on PHP but as those of you who know about PHP will understand, PHP will lose all it's available connections quite quickly, even under fpm.

So I turned to node.js which is supposed to be able to handle thousands, if not millions, of concurrent connections but the more I look it seems node.js handles these via event based programming. Of course event based programming has massive benefits.

This is fine for chat apps and what not but what if I have an online now feature that I have integrated into long polling to mark that a user is still online?

Would node.js still get saturated quickly or is it actually able to handle these open connections still?

Comment: why don't you use websockets for that? node.js has a wonderful library called socket.io and you can set that up in a few lines of code.

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything the problem is that everything I see is event based, and everything that scale seems to be event based. An onlne now feature isn't really event based, it just sits there going on

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything maybe the question should be: can node.js handle massive amount of simultaneous constantly open connections even without event based programming?

Comment: What does "event-based" have to do with constantly open connections? This question is not really clear.

Comment: Long polling is kind of a hack, and it'll eat up some of your available connections. It'll be a painpoint for scaling possibly. WebSockets aren't much better, and might be overkill. I don't think long polling should be too much of a burden, seeing as socket.io falls back to long polling I don't think theres any advantage to use websockets in your case. Long-polling isn't going to destroy your app. I'd assume it eat up some of your connection pool, but no more than a PHP implementation. If it becomes an issue you can just fall back to polling on short intervals.

Comment: All in all the only advantage you get from using websockets in your scenario is that you'll be one of the cool kids. Unless you're already opening a websocket for that page your just creating the same issue but with a different technology and you'd be shaving like 1% of overhead off your long polling. As far as your code is concerned its not going to hinder its performance, just make sure you set your `ulimit` high and maybe increasing node's connection pool size so that you don't exhaust your connection pool.

Comment: @Tomalak event based of course allows work to be done when needed. This is one thing that allows nginx to siphon off work as it is needed, not just whenever. Since node.js is non-blocking I assumed that it used event based programming as an internal method of understand when work was needed to be done much like nginx. I may have a misconception of how node.js works. It seems like help topics are a bit voodoo actually on the inner workings.

Comment: @tsturzl awesome thanks, I was also concern about websockets, they seemed a bit like "wait this is long polling but more complicated to implement, maybe a bit faster and less overhead since it is native to the browser"

Comment: @Sammaye websockets aren't very complicated to use and a great technology, but in your case adding websockets just to handle user's online status seems to be adding an entire technology to your stack to handle a pretty simple problem. Either way your issue is going to likely be with having a lot of open connections, websockets open persistent connections so you're not mitigating this issue using them. You're user's online status should be eventful, and I'm having a hard time understanding that also.

Comment: Shouldn't your long poll respond on the event when the other user/s disconnect or connect? That is an event. As long as your long-poll isn't looping looking at the status of each user compared to the previous state, then you should be fine. If you're doing this and cannot/don't want to move away from that paradigm you should poll on short intervals from the front-end and maintain state on your front-end.

Comment: @tsturzl One way I just thought of was pinging to node.js server the socket.io emit() but that is no better than short polling, I might as well just have an ajax call in my PHP do it to PHP

Comment: @tsturzl the problem is that this is actually running from PHP, it isn't solely a node.js app, I am using node.js as a means to stop PHP from dieing

Comment: If you're using PHP it might even be best to just keep your code base all in PHP otherwise you might be creating a headache. If you're not using an eventful paradigm I'm not entirely sure how you're going to implement long-polling without looping through your users and checking their state, and this will destroy your performance. Could you specify how exactly you intend to implement this in node in your answer?

Comment: @tsturzl the way I do is blindly set the online field to true and then a cronjob comes back later to detect last active ad set to false if needed, so all the code needs to do is like every so often set online to true in the user row

Comment: As an added note. If you're using php-fpm, long polling could get dirty, because fpm processes will timeout .

Comment: @tsturzl yeah, I keep the connection to 35 secs, I have that set out, but of coourse the better problem is that PHP has a process per connection, so even 5 open browsers can halt PHP fpm since PHP is not really designed for long polling

Comment: @Sammaye so you're periodically checking the database for the state of a user?

Comment: @tsturzl yeah but only from a cronjob, not node.js

Comment: @Sammaye You're absolutely right about that as well. You'll be spawning a process per connection.

Comment: @tsturzl I am hoping that I wont have that problem with node.js

Comment: Give me a bit and I'll sum all this up in an answer with some more detail.

Comment: One last thing. What dictates if a user is "offline"? When their session expires or they sign out, or when they leave a certain part of your application?

Comment: @tsturzl atm the cronjob will pickup all users who last active was 5 mins ago and just set them offline, straight from the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Long Polling with Node.js

Long Polling will eat up some of your connection pool, so be sure to set your `ulimit` high if using a Linux or Unix variety.

Ideally you'll maintain state in something like memcached or redis. A prefered approach would be to use Redis. For this you'll subscribe to a pub/sub channel, and everytime the user state updates you'll publish an event. This will trigger a handler which will cause your long-poll to respond with the updated status/s. This is typically prefered to scheduling and much cleaner, but as long as you're not looping or otherwise blocking node's thread of execution you shouldn't see any problems.

### Short Polling with PHP

As you're already using a PHP stack it might be prefered to not move away from that. PHP's(more so php-fpm) paradigm starts a process per connection, and these processes are set to timeout. So long polling isn't really an option.

Short polling on intervals can update the state on the front-end. As you specified that you are using cronjob, it might be cleaner to just hold the state in memory on the front-end and update it periodically.

This should work, however this might increase your need to scale earlier, as each user will be sending *n* more requests. However, this might be the easiest approach, and you're not adding unnecessary complexity to your stack.

### Websockets

Adding websockets for such a simple feature is likely overkill, and websockets themselves can only have a limited amount of connections(depending on your host and configurations) so you're not really solving any of the issues that long polling presents. If you don't plan to use websockets for more than just maintaining user state then you're adding another technology to your stack to solve a simple problem.